# ASP.NET ~/ not resolving to "/"

Tags: asp.net, path

My application paths …
    <a runat="server" href="~/Home">

…are resolving to “Home” (not “/Home”). After I rewrite URLs, “/Blah/Blah”, all the ”~/” links are relative to the rewrite: /Blah/Home

Is there a way to force a root to “/”?

Comment: You should pick an answer as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just write the links relative to the root ('/') instead of '~/', if you're application is not at the root of the domain, then the '~/' links will resolve to the root of the application

Comment: Thanks. I believe this is what I’ll do.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that, for the links in question you'll always be at a root of "/", then the simplest thing to do is change the <a> so that the href reads "/Home" rather than "~/Home" ... That way asp.net won't parse it and change it to use the App/VDir as its starting point.

Answer (score 0):

If you use standard HTML tags like a, then include the url via

```
<a href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Home")%>">...</a>
```

or use asp.net hyperlinks:

```
<asp:Hyperlink NavigateUrl="~/Home" runat="server" ID="HomeLink" Text="..." />
```

That way, all links will point to the right URL, even when the web application will be installed in a subdirectory.

`<% %>` is inline coding for asp.net, and `<%= %>` outputs the content, in that case the result of [ResolveUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

~/ gets translated in the web controls, as in  not   Otherwise, you need to use ResolveClientUrl to do that.

For the hyperlink control, it will automatically map correctly for you.